# Call a list class from controller

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How can I call my class list from controller?

Here are my models:

```
public class AuthJsonResponses
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Jwt { get; set; }
    //public string[] Message { get; set; }
    public List<RootObject> Message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I call in the controller:

```
List<RootObject> rootObj = new List<RootObject>();
rootObj[0].code = "success_04";
rootObj[0].msg = "Access granted";
JsonRes.Message = rootObj;
```

However there it seems there is a problem with the range which I don't know.
What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to initialize the list?

Comment: use rootObj.Add(new RootObject("success_04","Access granted"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handling the list like an array, which will not work, you need to make use of the `Add` method, for example

```
rootObj.Add(new RootObj{
    code = "success_04",
    msg = "Access granted"
});
```

You can also make use of the `AddRange` method to add multiple objects, for example

```
rootObj.AddRange(new List<RootObj>{new RootObj{
    code = "success_04",
    msg = "Access granted"
}, new RootObj{
    code = "success_05",
    msg = "Access denied"
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `List` actually you can use methods inherited from `IEnumerable` class, as List is an implementation of IEnumerable.

You can do this:

```
List<RootObject> rootObj = new List<RootObject>();
//delete this---- rootObj[0].code = "success_04";
//delete this---- rootObj[0].msg = "Access granted";
//use this
rootObj.Add(new RootObject{
code = "success_04",
msg = "Access Granted"
})
JsonRes.Message = rootObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access your `AuthJsonResponses` instance directly. First, update that class to make `Message` have a private setter and instantiate it as a `List<RootObject>`

```cs
public class AuthJsonResponses
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Jwt { get; set; }
    public List<RootObject> Messages { get; private set; } = new List<RootObject>();
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

In your code, directly add the object to the `Message` property.  I suggest renaming it to `Messages` to indicate it's a collection

```cs
jsonRes.Messages.Add(new RootObject{msg ="Access granted", code="success_04"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the things below :

```
 List<RootObject> rootObj = new List<RootObject>();
        var newObj=new RootObject()
        {
            code = "success_04",
            msg = "Access granted"
        };
        rootObj.Add(newObj);
        List<RootObject> rootObj1 = new List<RootObject>()
        {
            new RootObject()
            {
                code = "success_04",
                msg = "Access granted"
            }
        };
```

and then

```
JsonRes.Message = rootObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that your are refernecing first element of a list right afeter initializing the list! Initialization itself just creates the object of `List` class, **it does not create any elements**!

So, you have to create objects of `RootObject` class yourself and then add it to list:

```
// create object
var r = new RootObject();
r.code = "success_04";
r.msg = "Access granted";
// add it to list
rootObj.Add(r);
```